# an object reference is required for non static field method or property MyApplication.MyApplicationBl.TeamService.GetTeams()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

an object reference is required for non static field method or property MyApplication.MyApplicationBl.TeamService.GetTeams() error while calling the method in Action method

here is my interface

```
 public interface ITeamService : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams();
        Team GetTeam(int teamId);
        void AddTeam(Team team);
        void DeleteTeam(int teamId);
        void UpdateTeam(Team team);
        void SaveTeam();

    }
```

here is my MyApplicationBl.TeamService

```
public  IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams()
        {
            return preFlightDbContext.Teams.ToList();
        }

        public Team GetTeam(int id)
        {
            return preFlightDbContext.Teams.Find(id);
        }
```

here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var teams = from Team in TeamService.GetTeams()
                        select Team;
            return View(preFlightDbContext.Teams.ToList());

        }
        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            Team team = TeamService.GetTeam(id);
            return View(team);
        }
```

Comment: As error message said: An **object reference** is required for **non static** field method or property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a static method declaration:

`TeamService.GetTeams()`

Also `GetTeams` is not a static method, which means you will need an object to call that:

```
var teamService = new TeamService();

var teams = from Team in teamService .GetTeams()
                    select Team;
        return View(preFlightDbContext.Teams.ToList());
```

Comment: i have mentioned it in constructors
 public TeamController()
        {
           
            this.teamService = new TeamService(new PreFlightDbContext());
        }

Comment: But still you are doing `TeamService` and not `this.teamService`

Comment: i forgot to write the constructor . @Omri Aharon
Thanks